# Installing Ubuntu 13.04 on HP Pavilion g4 laptop

Tags: installation, 13.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 on my HP Pavilion g4 laptop ( Intel Core i3, 2GB RAM, Nvidia GeForce 610M with 1GB built-in memory), but I can't install it.

First I booted from the DVD drive and Choose language, and then my laptop screen went black. I waited for a long time, but it's still just a black screen.

1. How to install Ubuntu on my laptop?
2. Is Ubuntu 13.04 compatible with my laptop?

Comment: how did you create bootable ubuntu dvd?

Comment: Yes, I burned from ISO files.Dear Sir, please Reply and Help me. I really want to install .Thanks sir.

Comment: don't use sir i'm like you.why don't you create a bootable usb?

Comment: Yes, Thank friend , Let me use Friend. I tried and created to USB but it still .Thanks friend.

Comment: I tried 12.04 but black screen is still shown.

Comment: Do you meen it boots into black screen?if so you may find many answers here(http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: did you downloaded the ubuntu desktop version or sever version?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the ubuntu desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a different USB drive to mount the ISO and redo the process, because some USB drives are known to have problems with ISOs.

Don't go for the DVD drive option, as it is much slower as compared to USB install.

I would also recommend Wubi(Windows Installer) if you are dual-booting with Windows. It will be easier to remove Ubuntu if you ever need to.

Comment: Thanks, I will try again.If I have any inconvenient , please help me .